# Skip confirmation mail in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to skip the sending of confirmation mail from devise in my rails 4 application. I tried so many things, but none of them worked.

In my `user.rb`

```
before_create :my_method

def my_method
    self.skip_confirmation
end
```

I tried this also

```
before_create :my_method

def my_method
    !confirmed
end
```

I tried removing :confirmable from `user.rb` but none of them seems to work. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: after removing `:confirmable`, did u try to restart server ?

Comment: Did you try restarting rails server after the changes to model

Comment: make it like this `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable` save and restart  a server. It should skip confirming thing.

Answer (score 5):

> **Note**: If you want to skip only on certain places

If you are calling User.create before `skip_confirmation!`, you need to call `User.new` and `user.save`.

```
 @user = User.new(:first_name => "John", :last_name => "Doe")
 @user.skip_confirmation!
 @user.confirm!
 @user.save
```

A/C to your way

```
before_create :my_method

def my_method
    self.skip_confirmation!
    self.confirm!
end
```

> excluding the term `confirmable` in `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable` should skip in a whole

Comment: Hey thank u @illusionist :) but when I did second method I am getting this error "DEPRECATION WARNING: confirm! is deprecated in favor of confirm"

Comment: ok then use `confirm` instead, look proper method for the version of `devise` you are using.

Comment: `confirm` will now save the record which might not be desired.
`skip_confirmation!` will assign `confirmed_at` to the current time, which should eliminate the need to also call `confirm`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@user = User.new(:email => 'email@example.com', :password => 'password') 
@user.skip_confirmation_notification!
@user.save
```

`skip_confirmation_notification!` generate a confirmation token but does not send confirmation email.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to `user.rb`

```
protected

def confirmation_required?
 false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For every `User` instance:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize do |user|
    user.skip_confirmation_notification!
  end
end
```

For some particular instance:

```rb
john = User.new
john.skip_confirmation_notification!
```

P.S. The answers above are about disabling the confirmation process entirely, whereas the author asked about disabling just sending an email.